# Are Mallow and Geno unique to Super Mario RPG?

Tags: super-mario-rpg

Are Mallow and Geno unique to Super Mario RPG? Not so much Mallow, but Geno was very unique and I was wondering if he made any other appearances in other games. Super Mario Galaxy would be one of the games where I would suspect he could be featured or have a cameo...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Geno makes a small cameo in doll form in Mario & Luigi Superstar Saga. The [Super Mario Wiki](http://www.mariowiki.com/Geno) explains that

> he appears as the mechanical host of the Star 'Stache Smash arcade game in Little
>   Fungitown, explaining the rules of the minigame.

Mallow does not appear in any other games.

Comment: Geno has a Mii costume in Super Smash Bros for Wii U

Answer (score 6):

Mallow himself doesn't appear in any other games, but minor characters occasionally pop up who look like they might be from his species. Geno (or at least the doll he inhabited) had a cameo explaining one of the minigames in Mario & Luigi: Superstar Saga.

The most popular theory behind their rarity is that Square-Enix kept the rights to the original characters in Super Mario RPG, and generally does not allow Nintendo to use them again. This has never been officially confirmed one way or the other, but worth noting is that the end credits of M&L:SS *do* list Geno as belonging to Square-Enix. This confirms that Squeenix does indeed own those characters, and Nintendo really does have to get permission. But on the other hand, Nintendo *got* permission, at least for this case. Had Squeenix been refusing this whole time, and only relented this once? Or has Nintendo just never asked before? Nobody outside these companies is sure, and the people in a position to know aren't telling.

Answer (score -4):

That cloud power up from Super Mario Galaxy resembles Mallow from SMRPG!you're right! Geno did appear in superstar saga in little Fungi town!That's where they could be/are!