# Are the Nimbus people related to any other cloud entities?

Tags: super-mario-world, super-mario-rpg

After seeing [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/166923/are-mallow-and-geno-unique-to-super-mario-rpg), I began to wonder if the [Nimbus](http://www.mariowiki.com/Nimbus_People) race were featured in any other Mario games. I can see a common cloud theme throughout Mario games ranging from background clouds with eyes to [Lakitu's Cloud](http://www.mariowiki.com/Lakitu's_Cloud). Does anyone know of any evidence that these are related?

Comment: For whomever downvoted this question, can you please provide some reasoning in the comments?

Comment: Hey, that's my question :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nimbus people haven't appeared in any other game even as an easter egg to my knowledge. They certainly haven't become as abundant as say Lakitus or other series mainstays.

A single lakitu appears to be in the thrall of King Nimbus, the ["Royal Bus Driver"](http://www.mariowiki.com/Royal_Bus_Driver) (that's a bus?). However there are Lakitu all over SMRPG and most do not appear to have any affiliation to the Nimbus people so I wouldn't jump to make any association beyond "Square/Nintendo thought it made sense for a Lakitu transport in a cloud land".

Note that, possibly due to Intellectual Property issues with Squaresoft (now Square Enix), almost no characters/species introduced in Super Mario RPG have crossed over into future Mario offerings, despite Paper Mario being a perfect opportunity as a somewhat successor and frequent fan requests for Geno in Smash Bros.

Comment: How cool would it be to see Geno use his star powers in a Super Smash Brother's game?! Wow...this needs to happen.